Publishing private app to Managed Google Play
I'm trying to publish a private app to Managed Google Play.
According to this documentation,
I have to enable Managed Google Play on Release > Setup > Advanced settings > Managed Google Play.
There should be a button "Add organization" to add the organizations I want to make the app
available to. However, that button does not show up.

The app has not been published yet. Managed Google Play is enabled.
I contacted Google support twice, but I only got standard replies that tell me to RTFM.
Both tickets got closed immediately.
Do I need a Google Workspace account for publishing private apps? Can I get access to the
Admin Console without a Workspace account? According to this documentation,
I should be able to use a normal Google developer account and Google Play Console
for publishing private apps. The documentation also says that the Admin Console may be preferred over the Play Console when you want to skip the registration fee, so the Admin Console should be free as well, or is this a misinterpretation?
The account I'm using for Google Play Console appears to be an Organization account.
That's probably, because I chose "business" rather than "individual" when creating the account. Is this the reason why the "Add organizations" button does not show up?
But why would I have to create an account for an "individual" when I need to publish apps for our company?
